# Install windows update KB 2919355

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, visual-studio

Im trying to install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows Server 2012 R2. And even after run windows update and install everything cant install it.

[image]

Now I try to go the windows update [**page**](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=42334)

And even when show windows 2012, the link go to window 8 files

[image]
[image]

And if I try to install that file say the "update isn't applicable to this device"

[image]

And show the following error in the Event Log

> La actualización de Windows  no se pudo instalar debido a un error: 2149842967 "". (Línea de comandos: ""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\juan.oropeza\Downloads\Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu" ")

**So what I do to install the update?**

Comment: Have you seen issues in Event Log? Were there any another errors or warnings at time you tried install the update?

Comment: @Mr.Raspberry I add the event log message. Say error `2149842967 `

Comment: Seems to be quite a few  hits with suggestions about what needs to be applied.  https://www.google.com/search?q=KB+2919355+visual+studio+2015

Answer (score 0):

Try installing any other standalone update and see if that works.

Also, make sure Windows Update service is running and run updates from elevated cmd (run as administrator)

Try resetting Windows Update components and check if that helps. To do so run the Fixit form the link provided below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

If the issue still persists, run the System Update Readiness Tool. Follow the troubleshooting steps provided in KB article below and check if that helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821

Comment: In the windows link are like 6 different update, I could install everyone less than the one is asking Visual Studio. The Windows Update service is running.